# Line height distortion in IE

Tags: html, css

need a bit of help with a simple yet elusive fix to a strange css behaviour in IE.

The search bar text before each input box here http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html is off level in IE - so that only 'Search for' and 'in' are lower than the rest of the bar contents.

I can't see why this is happening, as the line height is the same for the entire search bar contents, so if anyone could shed some light, it'd be great!

Comment: It seems to be more than IE.  Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS present the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `&nbsp;` whitespace at the end of the container div;

```
<div>
<span>Search for:</span>
<input type="text" name="strGlobalSearch" value="e.g; restaurants, shops..." onclick="if (this.defaultValue == this.value) { this.value = ''; }">&nbsp;</div>
```

or

```
<span>Search for:</span>&nbsp;<input ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the SPAN around Search for:

```
<div>
 Search for:
 <input type="text" name="strGlobalSearch" value="e.g; restaurants, shops..." onclick="if (this.defaultValue == this.value) { this.value = ''; }">
</div>
```

Or alternatively remove the css declaration for the SPAN:

```
#menu-search span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

I don't think you need the SPAN or the CSS.